# Where is the ToEE Lurker Above described?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, published-adventures

I'm running the original [Temple of Elemental Evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Temple_of_Elemental_Evil) campaign in D&D 3.5e (with a lot of conversion help from the 'net) and I want to find a description of the *lurker above* monster. It seems that I cannot find it.

Does anyone know where this monster is described? Is there any description of this monster in D&D 3.5e?

Comment: Are you running the original ToEE campaign, just using 3.5 rules? Or are you running the *Return to the Temple of Elemental Evil* campaign that was published for 3.0? Or something else?

Comment: Original campaign, converted to 3.5 with some help from the ENworld conversion and lots of web searching and reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The description and stats for the Lurker Above can be found in the [Monster Mayhem: Lurker Above](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mm/20020719a) Wizards article.

Note that thse are D&D 3.0 stats, not 3.5 - some changes will be required to use them in a D&D 3.5 game.

Comment: The date and statblock suggest that that's 3.0 material; it needs updated space info, for example. It's not major, but you might note that it requires minor conversion, or even give suggested conversions. Good job finding it w/o saying "lmgtfy" ;)

Comment: @Chemus Ah, good point. Annoyingly, I can't find a 3.5 update anywhere.

Comment: @Adeptus the *asker* is not the only consumer of this question; others can benefit from this, too. And Miniman, I only meant that perhaps you note that its 3.0 material that needs minor updating, or that you make it up, noting that it's altered.

Comment: There is a pathfinder monster of that name as well.
If it is the same beast looking at both the original version and the PF version might help converting it to your needs.

: http://www.archivesofnethys.com/MonsterDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Lurker%20Above

Comment: Umbranus, I have come across the PF version. Also. I read that there is somewhere in the Underdark of FR the same monster. But I wanted a GH version :)

Comment: The *City of the Spider Queen* Web enhancement [(here)](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20020907a)—released 2 mo. after the Monster Mayhem column so it's technically official-er—includes *that exact same* lurker above minus the flowery opening if Forgotten Realms trade dress is preferred. There is no *3.5* update for the *CSQ* Web enhancement.